# No parameterless constructor defined for this object in MVC 5 while creating identity roles

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-roles

I am developing ASP.NET MVC 5 application for which i need Role-based authorization. While creating the new role i encounter error "No parameterless constructor defined for this object". Even tough i have defined the constructer.

**Here is my RoleController**

```
public class RoleController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationRoleManager _roleManager;

    public RoleController()
    {
    }


    public RoleController(ApplicationRoleManager roleManager)
    {
        RoleManager = roleManager;
    }

    public ApplicationRoleManager RoleManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _roleManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _roleManager = value;
        }
    }
    // GET: Role
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<RoleViewModel> list = new List<RoleViewModel>();
        foreach (var role in RoleManager.Roles)
            list.Add(new RoleViewModel(role));
        return View(list);
    }
    

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(RoleViewModel model)
    {
        var role = new ApplicationRole() { Name = model.Name };
        await RoleManager.CreateAsync(role);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

**Here is my RoleViewModel Class**

```
public class RoleViewModel
{
    public RoleViewModel (ApplicationRole role)
    {
        Id = role.Id;
        Name = role.Name;

    }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

**Here is my error message and stack trace**

*No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.*

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +142
System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +107
System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +13
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) +271

[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object. Object type 'DivComm.Models.RoleViewModel'.]
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) +345
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +750
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +446
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +137
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.b__0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +1082
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +163 System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +463 System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +48 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +73
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +163 System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +787 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +163
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +630
System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__20_0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +99
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +73 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +163
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +544
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +965
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +172
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Comment: Please share the entire error message, including stack trace and inner exceptions, if any.

Comment: I have updated my question and shared my entire error message, including stack trace – maybe that might be helpful to ascertain the cause of error

Comment: The information you provided makes the problem clear now. It's your Create action method. It takes a RoleViewModel as a parameter. However, the MVC model binder is choking because that class needs a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the issue is comming from `ApplicationRole` clase. No parameterless constructor defined for `ApplicationRole`. It is --

```
public class ApplicationRole
{
    public ApplicationRole (string name)
    {        
        Name = name;
    }
   //----- Properties

}
```

So your create post action will be --

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(RoleViewModel model)
{
    var role = new ApplicationRole(model.Name) { Name = model.Name };
    await RoleManager.CreateAsync(role);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

and your View Model--

```
public class RoleViewModel
{
    public RoleViewModel ()
    {

    }
    public RoleViewModel (ApplicationRole role)
    {
        Id = role.Id;
        Name = role.Name;

    }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Hopefully, it will be helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem persists. I have  updated my question and I have shared my entire error message, including stack trace

Comment: @Zahid you need to create a parameterless constructor for RoleViewModel as well. I updated my answer as well.